Mempool transaction Stream
I want to listen to the Solana mempool for a MEV bot. I was checking out Jito for this purpose, but it appears to be deprecated. How can I listen to the mempool transaction information on Solana now that Jito is no longer an option?
Thank you for your help.

Solana doesn't have a mempool -- mempool services typically exist as private solutions for searchers to get value from transactions.

Basically, I want to listen to the unConfirmed Transactions.
